# Nginx Reverse proxy on a internal apache reverse server

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

please check this diagram:

[image]

**The Setup:**

1) Nginx server are used to map to internal server where the apache is installed. 
2) Apache is on internal network which map to other server on same network that has tomcat installed on different port.
3) From internal network i able to test the apache is working fine with its

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass
```

4) From internal network, i able to access the Nginx Reverse Proxy(the nginx server's internal ip), it work fine and able to map until apache and its tomcat mapping.

**The problem:**
when i access the nginx's external ip from outside(public), i get following error:

```
504 Gateway Timeout nginx/1.3
```

what could be the issue? is there is anything else i need to set on apache or nginx so that i can access it from public?

does the apache's **ProxyRequests Off|On** will cause this issue? Currently set to Off

Comment: Apache has nothing to do but my guess is that something like a firewall is blocking connections from the reverse proxy to Apache. Check the error log of nginx.

Comment: you mean the firewall will cause : 504 Gateway Timeout nginx/1.3 ?

Comment: Yes. Nginx tries to connect to Apache but it gets a connection timeout when trying to connect. Have you checked the error log?

Comment: not yet, we dont have control over the nginx server, need to speak to network admin